# Force raw8 for debayering

Tags: ros, camera1394, image-proc

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have a Basler camera that outputs bayer pattern images in format7_mode1 mode. However, when I set raw8 for the format7_color_coding parameter, then it fails to be set, and mono8 is used instead. Therefore, the image_proc node cannot debayer the images, because it thinks they are simply grayscale, instead of bayer, as they actually are.

Everything works in coriander (see [coriander_bayer.png](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/13413943973522718.png)).

The output of the camera1394 node is

```
[ INFO] [1341392664.941249990]: using default calibration URL
[ INFO] [1341392664.941737294]: camera calibration URL: file:///home/enrique/.ros/camera_info/camera.yaml
[ERROR] [1341392664.942107239]: Unable to open camera calibration file [/home/enrique/.ros/camera_info/camera.yaml]
[ WARN] [1341392664.942363881]: Camera calibration file /home/enrique/.ros/camera_info/camera.yaml not found.
[ INFO] [1341392665.615791969]: Found camera with GUID 305300013759c6
[ INFO] [1341392665.616241698]: camera model: Basler A102fc
[ INFO] [1341392665.621517490]: Format7 unit size: (2x2), position: (2x2)
[ INFO] [1341392665.621664656]: Format7 region size: (1388x1038), offset: (0, 0)
[ERROR] [1341392665.624025892]: Color coding raw8 not supported by this camera
[ INFO] [1341392665.636889941]: using default calibration URL
[ INFO] [1341392665.637584961]: camera calibration URL: file:///home/enrique/.ros/camera_info/00305300013759c6.yaml
[ERROR] [1341392665.638324312]: Unable to open camera calibration file [/home/enrique/.ros/camera_info/00305300013759c6.yaml]
[ WARN] [1341392665.639039116]: Camera calibration file /home/enrique/.ros/camera_info/00305300013759c6.yaml not found.
[ INFO] [1341392665.639805838]: [00305300013759c6] opened: format7_mode1, 15 fps, 400 Mb/s
[ INFO] [1341392665.640524806]: camera calibration URL: package://cameras_cirs/calibration/basler_a102fc/format7_mode1/00305300013759c6.yaml
```

The message

```
Color coding raw8 not supported by this camera
```

of the output, is generated in modes.cpp file.

IMHO I think the best way to solve this is to allow the image_proc node to debayer mono8 images, so cameras that call mono8 to what should be raw8 are supported.

How can I force to set the raw8 encoding, or just debayer the images?
Thanks in advance.

Below you can see the launch and (parameters/config) yaml files I'm using to run the camera driver.

Enrique

**basler_a102fc_format7_mode1.yaml**
# Example camera parameters (for Basler A102fc)

```
# Parameters (no lens required/used)
guid: 00305300013759c6          # (defaults to first camera on bus)
iso_speed: 400  # IEEE1394a
video_mode: format7_mode1   # 1388x1038 @ 15fps bayer pattern
frame_rate: 15 # max fps (Hz)
format7_color_coding: raw8  # for bayer (we can use others, even rgb8 directly)
# With raw8, we don't need to configure bayer pattern and method, actually we
# cannot change them
bayer_pattern: gbrg
#bayer_method: HQ
auto_brightness: 3 # Manual (3)
brightness: 0
# Is better to increase gain than shutter speed, becuase gain produce salt&pepper
# noise, while shutter speed produce motion blur, which is harder to deal with.
auto_gain: 3 # Manual (3)
gain: 512 # dB unavailable
# See comment above wrt to gain and shutter speed setting.
auto_shutter: 3 # Manual (3)
shutter: 356 # time (ms) unavailable; value for sunlight
auto_white_balance: 3 # Manual (3)
white_balance_BU: 112
white_balance_RV: 64
frame_id: basler_a102fc
camera_info_url: package://cameras_cirs/calibration/basler_a102fc/format7_mode1/${NAME}.yaml
```

**basler_a102fc.launch**

```
<launch>
  <!-- Usage:
  roslaunch cameras_cirs basler_a102fc.launch view:=true
  -->

  <!-- Arguments -->
  <!-- Show video output (both RAW and rectified) -->
  <arg name="view" default="false"/>
  <!-- Camera params (config) -->
  <arg name="params"
       default="$(find cameras_cirs)/params/basler_a102fc/basler_a102fc_format7_mode1.yaml"/>

  <!-- Camera driver -->
  <node pkg="camera1394" type="camera1394_node" name="camera1394_node"
        output="screen">
    <rosparam file="$(arg params)"/>
  </node>

  <!-- Camera image processing (color + rectification) -->
  <node ns="camera" pkg="image_proc" type="image_proc"
        name="image_proc"/>

  <!-- Show video output -->
  <group if="$(arg view)">
    <!-- Image viewer (non-rectified image) -->
    <node pkg="image_view" type="image_view" name="non_rectified_image">
      <remap from="image" to="camera/image_color"/>
    </node>

    <!-- Image viewer (rectified image) -->
    <node pkg="image_view" type="image_view" name="rectified_image">
      <remap from="image" to="camera/image_rect_color"/>
    </node>
  </group>
</launch>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37862/force-raw8-for-debayering/) by [Enrique](https://answers.ros.org/users/244/enrique/) on ROS Answers with karma: 834 on 2012-07-03

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-07-03**:
If it works with coriander, then this is a bug in camera1394. Otherwise, it's a problem with the camera or the IEEE 1394 bus interface. Many cameras have flaky Format7 implementations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The first thing to try is to run coriander (`apt-get install coriander`) or other 3rd party software to make sure that this is a ROS related problem. I don't think that camera1394 has any internal logic to detect image type, it just queries the device which then tell whether the format is ok or not.

Could you run `camera1394` in a terminal and edit your question to add the exact error message? Could you try to see if other software support correctly the Format 7 mode of your camera?

If you want to debug the code, take a look at `src/format7.cpp` of `camera1394`. If there is a bug, it is probably lying around here.

PS: I don't have a FW camera available right now so you may have to use other tools if the format 7 support of coriander is not enough to replicate your issue, but I'm quite confident.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) with karma: 4478 on 2012-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Enrique](https://answers.ros.org/users/244/enrique/) on 2012-07-03**:
Yes, it works with coriander. I always try first with it :) That way I know the modes available and I can easily play with the controls and other options. And the format7 modes (0 and 1) are supported. And, sorry, I'd edit the comment in a moment with camera1394 output. Thanks.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-07-05**:
I still do not understand what is happening. Please open a defect ticket, linking back to this question: https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/newticket?component=camera1394&type=defect&&camera1394

**Comment by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) on 2012-07-05**:
Sorry for not answering after asking for more info, but same as joq. I don't quite get what is happening here... At this point, retrieving camera1394 from git and compiling it to debug manually is your best option...

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-07-06**:
Even without recompiling you can turn on debug output with rxconsole. That might give us a clue.

**Comment by [Enrique](https://answers.ros.org/users/244/enrique/) on 2012-07-18**:
I've just created the ticket: https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/5494, but I'm not able to test camera1394 with the same camera; some other guys are using it now, sorry.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2014-09-01**:
That Trac ticket has been copied to github issue #42: https://github.com/ros-drivers/camera1394/issues/42 . Please respond there is this is still a problem.